# Can run yarn command from one Power Shell window, but not another. What could possibly explain the difference?

Tags: powershell, rollupjs

**SUCCESS**

I start PowerShell from the File explorer: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. I change directory to where I want to run the yarn command. I run `yarn build` which starts the script `rollup --config --environment NODE_ENV:production`. The application builds successfully.

**FAIL**

I start PowerShell from the start menu: `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk`. This shortcut targets the executable above: `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. I change directory to where I want to run the yarn command. I run `yarn build`. The build errors.

```
src/renderer/renderer.tsx → app/build...
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src\renderer\renderer.tsx (6:9)
4:
5: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
6:   render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
            ^
7: );
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (C:\Users\Me\Dev\graphics\svgconverter\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:217:30)
    at Module.error (C:\Users\Me\Dev\graphics\svgconverter\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15145:16)
    at tryParse (C:\Users\Me\Dev\graphics\svgconverter\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15034:23)
    at Module.setSource (C:\Users\Me\Dev\graphics\svgconverter\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15436:30)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (C:\Users\Me\Dev\graphics\svgconverter\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:17434:20)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (C:\Users\Me\Dev\graphics\svgconverter\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:17495:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**LOOKING FOR DIFFERENCES**

- I have checked the file properties of the shortcut. It does not open the target as administrator. The owner is EUR/{Me}. System, Me and Administrators have all permissions checked except for special permissions. I think this is should not lead to any difference in behavior from starting PowerShell without using this shortcut?
- I have printed the environment variables on both shells using `dir env: | Format-Table -Wrap` and they are completely equal.

So now I am scratching my head. What could possibly explain the difference?

Comment: Have you tried with npm to discard is  yarn issue?